# Displaying jbehave steps in allure reports

Tags: automated-tests, bdd, jbehave, allure

Could anyone give me a hand please? I'm trying to use jbehave with allure reporting tool using the following example:

https://github.com/SergTanchenko/allure

But in the report only steps, annotated with "@Step" are displayed. Is there a way to show there given-when-then steps from .story file? Like they are displayed in thucydides reports:

http://www.thucydides.info/img/result-summary1.png

Comment: Being Allure developer I would say we're even not aware of this example. However let's wait for other developers to react.

Comment: Okay, but generally, is there any possibility of displaying jbehave steps in the reports? Maybe as a parent for @Step-annotated action(steps)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use both the annotations ( Jbehave annocations and allure annotation ). Process the test running using the Jbehave annotation and the report generation using the allure. Still attachment don't work, so you should have to customize your StoryReporter to include you screenshots seperately.